# How much does the Pathfinder Society pay for adventuring?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, campaign-settings

I'm running a campaign centered around the Pathfinder Society. The PCs have successfully become members. How much are they paid? I remember from the Pathfinder Guide that a pathfinder gets paid for successful missions, but how much? And does a pathfinder group keep the treasure it finds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You are not paid anything, but you gain benefits

Members of the [Pathfinder Society](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Pathfinder_Society) are loose affiliates, they are not hired adventurers. Being a member is like being part of an association with common goals, not a servant of an organization. Non-members are only required to respect each other and avoid conflict.

Those who are appointed as *Field Commissioners*, which are full members of the society, may be awarded a [Wayfinder](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Wayfinder), which is a magical compass enchanted to find the arcane marks on the [society's lodges](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Pathfinder_lodge). Contrary to non-members, field commissioners must report their explorations and adventures regularly

Being a field commissioner has a few benefits as well:

- They have a safe-house in the Pathfinder lodges, regardless of political or religious conflicts between members;
- Venture captains must offer shelter on their Pathfinder lodges;
- With this shelter comes many services, like rooms to sleep, libraries to research, meeting rooms and communication with other lodges if necessary;
- They have open access to any texts available on the lodge regarding that region where it is located: geography, politics, flora, fauna, etc;
- Their work can be published by the society and could gain a wide audience;

Though there is a list of known lodges, GMs are encouraged to create a lodge in any town big enough to hold one (usually 500+ people). Though Venture-Captains could charge for any services in the lodge, they rarely do unless they want to keep *freeloaders* away. You could find other services there though, such as magic item shops, temple services, hire servants and scholars, etc. It's all up to the GM though.

Other than all that, you are free to go and do as you please.

Comment: I was going by this definition of association: *groups of individuals who voluntarily enter into an agreement to accomplish a purpose*

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with you, I just think likening it to a trade union gets the point across better. If you disagree that's fine.

Comment: The Aspis Consortium is better defined as a trade union, as it is defined as "an unscrupulous multinational trade organization".

Comment: [Trade as in skilled labour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_union), not as in exchange of goods.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Pathfinder Society play and rules, standard Pathfinder agents get paid living and general travel expenses, but not much else. They are permitted to keep the majority of loot from missions (with some exceptions for certain artifacts or loaned gear). PFS play also seems to indicate field agents have time to pursue their own interests, since it allows a Day Job check after each scenario, where the PC can make money with a side job.